# How to round selection area in CollectionView?

Tags: .net, xaml

I want to make it so that when I click on an element, its background highlight will be rounded and not sharp at the ends. Help me solve this problem, I'm already tired

[image]

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 4" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged" Margin="20,0,20,0">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0,20,0,10">

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Border Stroke="{Binding Color}" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" HeightRequest="51" WidthRequest="51">
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
                        </Border.StrokeShape>

                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't, the system complains that the question consists of code and I can't provide more information